# 302 redirects from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: http, redirect, https

In a situation where a browser has to be redirected back to a http site from a https site, can this be done using a 302 (or 303) redirect without causing any security alerts from the browser?

The redirect target could be a different domain to the system that was providing the https content, so the browser may of been accessing pages from https://server.domain1.com/ and now needs to be redirected to http://different.domain2.com/

The redirect may also be in response to a form post, but without re-posting the data. Will browsers bring up a security warning as a result of the 302 redirect in this instance? Does 303 help with any security alerts? I'd like to avoid displaying what would essentially be a blank page with only a meta-refresh or javascript function to trigger the redirection.

I've been trying to find a list of browsers and their responses to both 302 and 303 in this situation, but can't find any such list.

Answer (score 0):

A normal redirect http to https should not trigger a warning (expect in iframe for example) but a POST from an https page to an http page may trigger a warning.

And in any case, you should think about the safety of your users and use https rather than trying to avoid legitimate warnings.