# Allowing HTTP API calls in Chrome

Tags: api, google-chrome, http, jsp, web-frontend

I am writing a test JSP-Servlet page that calls an HTTP API. But when I run the call in Chrome browser it is converting the call to HTTPS and the call fails. The API is not mine and the developer of the API insists that the call has to be on HTTP.

So is there a way to allow this API call using HTTP and prevent Chrome from converting it to an HTTPS call?

**Note:** I checked the Web and all are saying to change the browser settings. But we will not be able to tell each and every user of our site to do so!

Comment: Will this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586593/15590269

Comment: For development this will help me but, when deployed we cannot say to each and every end user to make this changes in desktop / mobile Chrome browser settings to use our API.

Answer (score 0):

### Add this Script on top of your JSP File!

```
<script>
if (location.protocol == "https:") {
    location.protocol = "http:";
</script>
```

**Note:**
First, `location.protocol` checks Url
and the second `location.protocol` will change it to http.

This will redirect your Client. If he visits your website as `https:` it will redirect him as `http:`

Comment: Ok thanks `Sam Joshua` this will work with direct JSP calls what to do about 302 redirect calls?

Comment: @Natraj Will this Help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380/15590269

Comment: @Natraj Check this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/36679908/15590269

Comment: Sorry `Sam Joshua` this does not help

Comment: @Natraj Sorry, for this late reply! You can use link shorteners like rebrand.ly Which will redirect to your project as HTTP! Will this help you? Plz, reply as fast as possible!